# Xpath with column headers?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am looking to generate the XPath for the XML below. The "cname" nodes are column headers and the "c" nodes are the values for each node. So it represents one row in a dataset.

Each row of the dataset also has a timestamp which is determined by the "time_stamp", "time_delta" and "epoch" attributes in the "data" node.

So when the XML is parsed, each row will look something like:

```
timestamp|cname value|c value.
```

I am new to XPath, so I'm struggling to figure out how to make it all work.

```
<group serial="0x757c6ce4">
    <data columns="13" time_stamp="0x582e5290" time_delta="3600" epoch="0x58110bb8">
        <cname t="P">Grid</cname>
        <cname t="S">Grid*</cname>
        <cname t="P">Gen Set</cname>
        <cname t="S">Gen Set*</cname>
        <cname t="I">I CT1</cname>
        <cname t="I">I CT2</cname>
        <cname t="I">I CT3</cname>
        <cname t="I">I CT4</cname>
        <cname t="I">I CT5</cname>
        <cname t="I">I CT6</cname>
        <cname t="V">V L1</cname>
        <cname t="V">V L2</cname>
        <cname t="V">V L3</cname>
        <r>
            <c>5767921882</c>
            <c>9191660779</c>
            <c>-10086911</c>
            <c>74160204</c>
            <c>6797464335</c>
            <c>13344163875</c>
            <c>22469766027</c>
            <c>434394781</c>
            <c>370902463</c>
            <c>584404781</c>
            <c>363009180326</c>
            <c>358965953018</c>
            <c>302435738676</c>
        </r>
    </data>
</group>
```

Comment: Do you have the possibility to use XSLT to create the output?

Comment: nope.  this is data coming from an iot device and being parsed by a gateway before storage. the gateway requires an xpath input to read the xml data.